# WPF Calendar disable date selection

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi guys i want a way to disable date selection in a WPF calendar.

i tried the disabled property but i want to navigate from dates, i have selected dates by default and dont want the user to be able to select dates.

This is my calendar code:

```
<Calendar x:Name="show_Calendar" IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" />
```

and i select dates like this:

```
SelectedDatesCollection dates = new SelectedDatesCollection(show_Calendar);
foreach (var item in TaskManagerClass.revisionesTarea(tareaActiva.Id))
{
   if (item.DiaRevision.HasValue)
     dates.Add(item.DiaRevision.Value);
}
```

I want the user to be able to navigate between months but cannot select dates from the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may disable the selection of dates by setting the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the `CalendarDayButton` to `false` using a `Style`:

```
<Calendar x:Name="show_Calendar" IsTodayHighlighted="False" SelectionMode="MultipleRange">
    <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
</Calendar>
```